# Compiler error with @override when overriding an interface method on JDK 7u2

Tags: java, android

I know, this sounds like an old question, which has been asked before(***). But it is a little bit different. I installed a clean system with the newest versions of JDK (7u2) and eclipse (and also AndroidSDK). When I import old projects, I get an error "The method methodName(Parameter) of type Class must override a superclass method".

The @override-tag was there (correctly), because the method overrides a method of an INTERFACE of the superclass. somehow compiler thinks that this tag is just for superclass directly. As far as i know @override is not changed in Java 7 and my project was working properly on 6. Is it a possible bug or compability problem or I am missing something?

(***)Similar problem used to happen, when compiling on JDK5, simply because @override was yet implemented in Java 5. Solution was, of course changing compiler compliance level to 6. But what is it with JDK 7 now?

Comment: Have you checked compiler compliance settings in Eclipse?

Comment: yes. it is on JDK 7. Currently no other JDKs are installed anyway.

Comment: Compliance level should be 1.6, no matter if it's JDK6 or JDK7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use JDK 7 for the development. There is a [requirement](http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html) that you have to use JDK 5 or 6.

Comment: Actually my real problem was something else: The "fix project properties" option of the eclipse plug-in was forcing the project to use compliance level 5 and I didn't see it.